# Scraping Javascript rendered elements of a webpage in Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I am looking to scrape the data that feeds the SVG elements of this page:

https://www.beinsports.com/au/livescores/match-center/2019/23/1074885

The page appears to be Javascript rendered, so traditional uses of BeautifulSoup in Python are not working. I have refreshed in the Inspect Network XHR and it does not appear the page stores the data in JSON either. However, when refreshing the JS page in the Network, I see F24_8.js, which in the preview shows exactly what I would want to capture that is feeding the SVG elements:

[image: F24_8.js]

Is there a way to run a script from selenium as an example to mimic that javascript rendering and retrieve the backend data at issue here?

Per a request in the comments, I've included a script below that worked against a similar page that is no longer supported by the domain. In that case, executing the script to serialize the XML was more straightforward given the existence of the XML script, and that page did not display the row-level detail but the script fed the row-level data that was used in the rendered tools:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import math
import time

games=[]

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get("http://www.squawka.com/match-results")
WebDriverWait(browser,10)

mySelect = Select(browser.find_element_by_id("league-filter-list"))
mySelect.select_by_visible_text("German Bundesliga")

seasons=['Season 2012/2013','Season 2013/2014','Season 2014/2015','Season 2015/2016','Season 2016/2017','Season 2017/2018']
for season in seasons:
    nextSelect = Select(browser.find_element_by_id("league-season-list"))
    nextSelect.select_by_visible_text(season)

    source=browser.page_source
    soup=BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')
    games.extend([a.get('href') for a in soup.find_all('a',attrs={'href':re.compile('matches')})])

    pages=math.ceil(float(soup.find('span',{'class':'displaying-num'}).get_text().split('of')[-1].strip())/30)
    for page in range(2,int(pages)+1):
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"pg='+str(page)+'")]').click()
        source=browser.page_source
        soup=BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')
        games.extend([a.get('href') for a in soup.find_all('a',attrs={'href':re.compile('matches')})])

    print '---------\n'+season+' Games Appended'

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import lxml.etree as etree

frames=[]
count=0
for game in g2:

    try:
        url = game

        browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        browser.get(url)

        time.sleep(10)

        page = browser.execute_script('return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(squawkaDp.xml);')
        root = etree.XML(page.encode('utf-8'))

        #events
        gm=pd.DataFrame()
        for f in root.iter('filters'):
            for a in f:
                for event in a.iter('event'):

                    d=event.attrib
                    records=dict((x,[y]) for x,y in d.items())
                    new_records=dict((x.tag,[x.text]) for x in event)

                    r=pd.DataFrame(records)
                    nr=pd.DataFrame(new_records)
                    j=r.join(nr)
                    j['category']=a.tag

                    gm=gm.append(j)
```

I recognize the incompleteness of the script but the remaining details are not necessary to the question at hand.

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: Expected output is tabular data including id, event_id,...,x,y,assist,...,version

Comment: what's an actual example row of values from that table? Not just the descriptions of column headers. And where is your current code please?

Comment: i don't currently have an example of values from that table, as they don't populate directly to the page itself but the records feed the tools being displayed/rendered

what i do have is a previously-working script that ran against a different webpage doing similar things, which i will update the OP with for clarity

Answer (score 0):

If you use Selenium, you can use `driver.execute_script("your script here")` to run Javascript on the page.

I have only used this with very short scripts such as `arguments[0].click();`, with success, but I'm not sure how this will work for longer scripts.

```
driver = new webdriver.Chrome()

driver.execute_script("your script here")
```

You can also run scripts against WebElements, using the `arguments[0]` in Javascript.

```
my_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='someText']")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", my_element)
```

This will pass `my_element` into the JS function as `this`.